# Find out value of select box with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm really new to jQuery so sorry if this is simple, however I have a select box, with values in it. At the moment on select it shows a div.

```
<div class="three columns"><select name="selectbox1" id="selectbox1" style="width:60px;"><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></div>

<div class="twelve columns" id="itemadd"><p class="itemadd">You have sucessfully added a child seat at 3 Euros per day.</p></div>
```

And a simple hide function:

```
$('#itemadd').hide();
        $('#selectbox1').change(function() {
            $('#itemadd').show();
        });
```

I would like to be able to find out the value of the selectbox and use it in a variable as well, so I can display a slightly more interactive message and also use it in pricing.

```
$("#selectbox1").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
});
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

All I want to do is if the select is selected and the value is 4 for example, I want to be able to know that and put it into a variable so I can reuse it. In messages or sums.

Comment: What you tried should work. Can you show us how you're using the `id` variable that you set with `$(this).val()`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the valu of variable 'id' from other functions then declare 'id' variable outsite the jquery handler.

ex:

```
      var id ;
        $('#itemadd').hide();

        $('#selectbox1').change(function() {
        $('#itemadd').show();

        });


       $("#selectbox1").change(function() {

              id = $(this).val();
              call();  

             });

           function call()
          {
             alert(id); //use the value here
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectbox1').change(function() {
    var valueSelected=$("#selectbox1 option:selected").val();
    $('#itemadd').text("You have sucessfully added a child seat at "+valueSelected+" Euros per day.");
    $('#itemadd').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

1)In HTML I have added a `span` tag as a placeholder to display the value selected.

2)Initially i am `hiding` the `itemadd` section. `On change` of the selectbox, i have got the **selected value** and **stored** it **in** a variable `selvalue`.
This stored variable value , i am displaying it inside the `span` tag using `text()` function.
And in the end i am displaying the whole `itemadd` section.

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg6sof86/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="three columns">
   <select name="selectbox1" id="selectbox1" style="width:60px;">
      <option>0</option><option>1</option>
      <option>2</option><option>3</option>
      <option>4</option><option>5</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="twelve columns" id="itemadd">
   <p class="itemadd">You have sucessfully added a child seat at <span class="selected-val">3 </span>  per day.</p>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$('#itemadd').hide();
    $('#selectbox1').change(function() {
         var selvalue= $(this).val();           
        $(".selected-val").text(selvalue);
        $('#itemadd').show();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

should be like this.

```
$("#selectbox1").change(function() {
    var select_val = $("#selectbox1").val();
    alert(select_val);
});
```

Comment: What the OP has got is directly equivalent to this in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
    $("#selectbox1").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).children(":selected").html();
    }); 
});
```

[working js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkuep/)

Comment: You probably want `val()`, not `html()`, and regardless, this is what calling `val()` does directly on the `<select />` element, so again, is no different what the OP is already doing.

Comment: @Matt - surely I know that anything can be used but I always use .html(). whats wrong with that? with it if you might have noticed on the fiddle I have added a $(function(){}) just in case he forgot that.

Comment: Parv: An `<option>` should contain no HTML, so calling `text()` would be the best approach here in that situation. As for the differences between `val()` and `text()`, see http://jsfiddle.net/Lkuep/2/ (set the `<select />` back to "Blah blah blah"). Maybe if your answer was more than just a code block with no explanation, it might make it clearer what exactly you've added to your answer. Regardless, your introduction of `var val = $(this).children(":selected").html();` serves no purpose.

Comment: @Matt - ok I should have used .text() instead of .html() and I have used .html() because there is no value attribute defined.

Comment: Parv: Well for future reference, note that (as shown in my jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lkuep/1/)), if `value` isn't specified, its default value is the text content of the element; so they're one-and-the-same :)

Answer (score -1):

`$("#selectBox option:selected").val()` // to get the value of option selected

`$("#selectBox option:selected").text()` // to get the text of option selected